# How to find $a\mod N $ in a specific way?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let's I have an integer a and take it's modulo with M (**M is a prime Number**) which is b.
i.e. $b  = {a\mod M}$
I would like to get $a \mod N$    by doing some operation on operation on b along with M , N  ? .
i.e. [$a\mod N$] = [b **some operation with** N , M] 

e.g. a =  20 , M = 23 and N=15
then $b = a\mod M$
so , $b = 20 $ 
$a\mod N = 5 $. 
 There is any way to get 5 by doing some operation on b along with M , N  ?

**Note : Here I used square brackets to represent together $a\mod N$ .**

Comment: If $N$ is a factor of $M$, then there's no need to do anything as $b\equiv a\pmod M$ the implies that $b\equiv a\pmod N$ (if you are interested in remainders instead of congruence, you can calculate the remainder of $a$ modulo $N$). But if $N$ is not a factor of $M$, then the operation is not well defined. For example $12, 22 $ and $32$ all have remainder $2$ modulo $10$, but their remainders modulo $7$ are $5,1$ and $4$ respectively, so there cannot be a magic formula for getting all of those starting with only $2$ and $7$ without information about the number you started with.

Comment: How about? $\gcd(a,N,M)$

Comment: @FredKline can you elaborate ?I am not getting what you are asking ?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen can we solve updated problem . Where M is prime number .

Comment: Same problem. In my numerical example let's use $M=11$ instead of $10$. Then $12,23$ and $34$ all leave remainder $=1$ modulo $11$, but their remainders modulo $7$ are $5,2$ and $6$ respectively. It may be the first time you try to describe a function that is **not** *well defined*. This is what means. Modular arithmetic is full of pitfalls like this, if you want to switch the modulus (here from $11$ to $7$) in the middle of a calculation.

Answer (score 2):

If $N>M$, that looks difficult, because $b$ can take $M$ different values, while $a\bmod N$ can take $N$ different ones.

If $N<M$, it looks difficult as well, because any $a=b+kM$ will give the same $b$, while $$a\bmod N=(b + kM)\bmod N=(b + (kM\bmod N))\bmod N$$
can take any value.

Comment: When I say it looks difficult, I mean it is not possible.